# The best way to check the best match contains String?

Tags: javascript

I have a String and want to determine whether the best String is contained by another String.

I'll try to explain by JS code like this:

```
function A(){
    var str = "The best way to check the best match contains String?";

    if(str.includes("The")){ //<== This is not the best match, but currently return this
        return "1";
    }
    if(str.includes("The best")){
        return "2";
    }
    if(str.includes("The best way1")){
        return "3";
    }
    if(str.includes("The best way")){ //<=== Should to return this
        return "4";
    }
}
```

I don't want to swap the if conditions by hand. Because maybe the list check and results want to return is dynamic or load from somewhere like:

```
    const objCheck = {
        "The": "1",
        "The best": "2",
        "The best way1": "3",
        "The best way": "4"
    }
```

Any idea for this?

Comment: @Andreas I think all of the things I formated are code?

Comment: `Object.entries()` + `.reduce()`

Comment: Okay, thank you. Can you explain more?

Comment: `The best way1` isn't in the string

Comment: @Terry That's why the result should be `4`

Comment: @Terry yup, so it'll not return. Because maybe `str` variable is from parameters

Comment: just keep a variable inside the fuction that goes through all if checks and finally return it?

Comment: @cmgchess You don't get my point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on your object to get an array of key-value pairs of the shape:

```
[["The", "1"], ["The best": "2"], ...]
```

Above, an inner array represents an *entry* (ie: a key, value pair from your object). Once you have this array, you can [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) based on the length, so that the entries with the longest *key* appear first in your array. Once sorted, you can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first entry that has a key that is included in your search `str`. Lastly, you can use `?.pop()` to grab the number value associated with the key that is found. The `?.` here is the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator which is used to ensure that we don't try and call `.pop()` if `.find()` is unable to find any entries:

```js
const objCheck = {
  "The": "1",
  "The best": "2",
  "The best way1": "3",
  "The best way": "4"
};

function findBestMatch(str, obj){
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => b.length - a.length)
    .find(([substr]) => str.includes(substr))
    ?.pop();
}

var str = "The best way to check the best match";
console.log(findBestMatch(str, objCheck));
```

If you need something a little more efficient, you can avoid the sorting by maintaining the max value seen so far as you loop through your array:

```js
const objCheck = {
  "The": "1",
  "The best": "2",
  "The best way1": "3",
  "The best way": "4"
};

function findBestMatch(str, obj){
  let res, best = -Infinity, entries = Object.entries(obj);
  for(const [substr, num] of entries) {
    if(substr.length > best && str.includes(substr)) {
      best = substr.length;
      res = num;
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}

var str = "The best way to check the best match";
console.log(findBestMatch(str, objCheck));
```